# Primefaces Ajax Datatable rowSelect only firing on some whitespace

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable which contains a list of objects but I am trying to make selection drive the contents of a child datatable with very inconsistent results.

The issue I am having is that the `rowSelect` event is only firing when I click on certain parts of the row.   Clicking in the white space after the button gives 100% success but anywhere else is very hit and miss.   Clicking on the text of the name column never selects the row or fires the event.  I added a radio button column and clicking inside the radio button selects the radio button and highlights the row but again does not fire the event (clicking in the whitespace around the radio button works fine).

This is with PrimeFaces 10 and I have checked in both Chrome and Edge.

It is driving me crazy and all I want is for a user to be able to click on a row and for this to update the child datatable but as it stands this is unusable.   When the event does fire, everything updates correctly so it must be the JSF that is causing the problem.

```
<h:form id="form>
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
<p:dataTable id="myDataTable" var="rec" value="#{myBean.myObjList}" editable="true" selection="#{myBean.myObj}" rowKey="#{rec.id}">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myBean.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" process="myDataTable"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myBean.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" process="myDataTable"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.onRowSelect}" update=":form:myChildDataTable" process="myDataTable"/>
    <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
    <p:column headerText="Name">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{rec.name}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{rec.name}" style="width:100%" label="Name"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:6rem">
        <p:rowEditor/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:6rem">
        <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-times" styleClass="ui-button-danger" action="#{myBean.deleteRecord(rec)}" update=":form:myDataTable,:form:msgs">
            <p:confirm type="popup" header="Confirmation" message="Do you want to delete this record?" icon="pi pi-info-check"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Try without `p:cellEditor` (which you probably don't want). I don't think it is intended for you to be able to use both at the same time.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I do want the `p:cellEditor` (I think).   This page is to maintain a set of three hierarchical database tables.  I want to be able to select the top level parent and this will populate the next level and selecting one of those will load the grandchildren.   I also however want to be able to create and amend items.   Taking it out does mean I can select the row clicking on the text but obviously I can no longer edit it.    Interestingly the radio buttons still don't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160667/row-selection-with-cell-editor-in-primefaces-datatable-makes-it-difficult-to-sel

Guess I need to change how I approach this.